# Unable to encode uri component

Tags: api, rest, google-apps-script

I am trying to send encoded params as encoded uri component please view the code below:

```
params= {"requester":{"first_name": "hello@abc.com","email_id": "hello@abc.com", "login_user":"true"}};
    encodedpURL=encodeURIComponent(url+'?'+params);
    console.log(encodedpURL);
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(encodedpURL, options);
```

The encodedURIComponent converts the url as

```
https%3A%2F%2Fhelpdesk.com%2Fapp%2Fitdesk%2Fapi%2Fv3%2Frequesters%3F%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

**The Use Case**

1. Send encoded query params to post data through API.
2. Query Params: Key = input_data, Value = `{"requester":{"first_name": "hello@abc.com","email_id": "hello@abc.com", "login_user":"true"}}`
3. The Value must be sent as Encoded URI Component.
4. API Call

   ```
   var url = "https://helpdesk.com/app/itdesk/api/v3/requesters";
   var options = {
              "method": "post",
              "headers": {
                               "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",  
                               "Accept": "application/vnd.manageengine.sdp.v3+json",            
                               "Authorization": "Zoho-oauthtoken "+apisheet[1][0]
                         },
   "muteHttpExceptions": true
             };`
   ```

Any reference of help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I suspect the `params` should be a string. But it is an object. You can convert an object into a string with: `JSON.stringify(params)`. But I have no idea if this is a cause of the problem in this particular case.

Comment: You're  missing `Key = input_data`. Send the data directly: ```payload:{'input_data':`{"requester":{"first_name": "hello@abc.com","email_id": "hello@abc.com", "login_user":"true"}}`}```